# Show block only on node view page, not in node create or edit form

Tags: 7, blocks

How can I configure block visibility to show only in node view pages? (not in node edit and create pages)

What should I insert in "Show block on specific pages" > "Only the listed pages"? current config is:

```
video
node/*
```

Comment: Use `contenttypes` instead of `pages`. Then select all contentypes.

Comment: and what about video page? which is a list of videos created in views

Comment: Make a block of the view and display it on a page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this in your block configurations page "Show block on specific pages" > "Show if the following PHP code returns TRUE"

```
if(arg(0) == 'node' && is_numeric(arg(1)) && ((arg(2) == "" || arg(2) == 'view'))) {
  return TRUE;
}
```

Hope this will help.

You will need to enable the core module PHP.

Comment: Should I enable any module?

Answer (score 4):

I use the [Context](http://drupal.org/project/context) Module for this. It allows a more fine grained control than the out-of-the-box drupal-options.

Comment: +1 Context is definitely the best suited for this type of thing. Only thing with Context at the moment is it can't handle "Block Configurations" per context, you need to configure the block from the block admin screen.

Answer (score 1):

Select the block you wish to exclude and add '*/edit' and '*/add/*' to the 'Pages' tab in the 'Visibility settings'. You can use 'Content types' in combination with these settings to fine tune a bit further.
[image: edit/add]

Comment: This one is one is the best answer, it is simple and does require additional modules like PHP or Context.